# MissMDA Bayesian MIPCA help/MIFAMD

Tags: r, bayesian, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

While looking into methods relating to principal components related imputation, I came across MissMDA package in R. Could anyone please tell me what the Bayes in the MIPCA means in layman terms? I have some trouble understanding the paper as I am rather weak in grasping math/statistical concepts (I am still learning)...

In addition, something interesting I found - MIPCA is dedicated to only continuous variables and that excludes encoded categorical variables. Hoping that this finding will help someone who faces the same confusion as I had initially about the package. It is recommended to use MIFAMD instead because its designed for mixed data.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited resources online, I tried my best to decipher the related papers and also confirmed with Dr Josse, one of the authors for MissMDA.

Bayesian PCA imputation in layman terms: 
1.  Imputation by random draw from posterior distribution given current parameters in dataset 
2.  Draw from recalculated posterior distribution by complete dataset from set 1, given PCA applied on dataset from set 1

FAMD in layman terms: 
1.  Missing values imputed with initial values such as mean of variable for continuous variables and proportion of category for each category 
2.  Perform FAMD on complete dataset 
3.  Impute missing values with reconstruction formula to compute a fitted matrix. Missing values will be replaced by fitted values 
4.  Repeat until convergence

Hope it helps someone out there! :)

Related research papers: 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.4797.pdf 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299498837_missMDA_A_Package_for_Handling_Missing_Values_in_Multivariate_Data_Analysis 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missMDA/missMDA.pdf 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5747.pdf 
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1549-bayesian-pca.pdf